# Automatically get notified when a database record is updated

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, real-time

I have an oracle client database with 500k client records. Every month i run a batch process to produce some monthly analytical using the client data. But sometimes, the database owner tells me that they have updated the data and i need to run the batch again.

I would like to build a monitoring /notification service that will immediately tell me when a particular client record got updated and what was the update. That way i know if the update can be ignored or not.

I can of course run an hourly sql query that compares each client record with its previous snapshot but is there a better solution?
Does something like Kafka work in this scenario? How exactly?

Comment: Sure, you could use kafka (see, for example, something like this) https://blogs.oracle.com/bigdataconnectors/integrating-data-in-motion-with-data-at-rest-using-oracle-sql-access-to-kafka-views But that seems like overkill for a relatively small table that may or may not get updated every month.  Personally, it sounds like a simple trigger that writes to a history table and a process that polls that history table daily or hourly would be sufficient.  Or try to send an email from the trigger if you want quicker notifications.

Comment: "Every month i run a batch process " why do you need real time like Kafka? I agree this is overkill. You just need a trigger and a log table. Or there are many other out of the box methods in Oracle to know if table was updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Continuous Query Notification (previously known as Database Change Notifications).

Read more about it:

- [DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION with examples](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.html)
- [Continuous Query Notification for JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/continuos-query-notification.html#GUID-4987516F-872F-47D1-B9E7-270A28D50AF8)

@JustinCave also suggests a pretty good option to create simple trigger and enable it only when you really need it, but probably it would be easier just to create materialized view log and check it periodically for new changes. You can get changed rows from it.

Simple example:

```sql
SQL> create table t(id int primary key, a int, b int);

Table created.

SQL> create materialized view log on t with primary key, rowid;

Materialized view log created.

SQL> select log_table from user_mview_logs where master='T';

LOG_TABLE
--------------------------------
MLOG$_T

SQL> desc mlog$_t
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 M_ROW$$                                            VARCHAR2(255)
 SNAPTIME$$                                         DATE
 DMLTYPE$$                                          VARCHAR2(1)
 OLD_NEW$$                                          VARCHAR2(1)
 CHANGE_VECTOR$$                                    RAW(255)
 XID$$                                              NUMBER

SQL> column M_ROW$$ format a20;
SQL> column CHANGE_VECTOR$$ format a10;
SQL> select * from mlog$_t;

no rows selected

SQL> insert into t(id, a, b) values(1,1,1);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from mlog$_t;

        ID M_ROW$$              SNAPTIME$$          D O CHANGE_VEC      XID$$
---------- -------------------- ------------------- - - ---------- ----------
         1 AAASWNAAMAAAAEXAAA   4000-01-01 00:00:00 I N FE         2.8148E+15
```

Comment: Don't create an MV Log for that purpose; they're intended to be used internally by Oracle and only to hold a relatively small number of changes until they are read by a fast refresh materialized view, at which point Oracle automatically clears the log. If you don't have a mechanism to regularly - frequently - clean out that log, it will grow indefinitely and begin to degrade overall DB performance.

Comment: @pmdba it's fully documented thing, read more about it: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-MATERIALIZED-VIEW-LOG.html#GUID-4DAD5E6F-E30A-43D0-B023-634752E0E627

Comment: And especially this https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-MATERIALIZED-VIEW-LOG.html#GUID-13902019-D044-4B79-9EB4-1F60652D037B

Comment: I have used both MVs and MV Logs extensively over the years. From the first line of the doc you reference: "A materialized view log is a table associated with the master table of a materialized view." or "materialized view log, which is a table associated with the master table of a materialized view." It's purpose is to support a materialized view. As far as Oracle is concerned, it has no other supported purpose. Having to use DDL instead of DML to maintain it should also raise a red flag.

Comment: A trigger on the table could still track changes in a history table and could fire notifications directly without need of a separate scheduled process, embedded DDL in application code, or the need to further work-around and hack something into a purpose for which it was not intended (and the mechanism for which Oracle could change without warning).

Comment: 1. Again, it's fully documented feature, without any restriction for use only for mviews; moreover, it's officially deployed and supported by oracle on 3 big sites I know about (banking) 2. Creating or enabling a trigger is also a DDL, the same way as creating cqn.

Comment: Creating an object is always DDL, but maintaining data should never be. From the AskTOM site: "It sounds like you're trying to use an MV log as some kind of audit log or change history. That's not what it's for.

Their purpose is to track changes for tables you use in materialized views. So the database can use these to do a fast refresh. i.e. just apply the last few insert/update/deletes to the MV, instead of having to rerun the full query from scratch." https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=materialized-view-log.

Comment: You can't delete rows from an MV log;  you have to use an ALTER MV LOG DDL command to purge it; that's DDL in the application code, not just the data model like create trigger. Using an MV Log as change history is an inappropriate, unsupported use of the feature.

Comment: Please read carefully purge clause on create materialized view log. And again oracle employees suggested and implemented the use of mview logs for change tracking (fast deltas) in one of biggest companies ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ it's very very old approach and I still see it's used very often

Comment: I align with CQN as the best solution to this question. Further, can we publish the output of the CQN as an AWS SNS topic or what are the output types from a CQN? Can the CQN trigger a Lambda Function directly to achieve another task?